# Resize and reposition view and it's children from within its ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have a view automatically resize itself and its children based on the screen resolution of the device.
I have found that the only way to do this is to put the resize code in the viewDidLayoutSubviews() function.  The problem with putting everything in that function is when I resize the mainView, it causes viewDidLayoutSubviews to be called again, causing an infinite loop.
I even tried adding a timer and calling the resize code when the view is finished setting itself up, but nothing appears to happen.

```
class PeopleVC: 
{
@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
var topNav:TopNavigationView!

@IBOutlet weak var peopleTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!

let simpleTableIdentifier = "TableViewCell"

var currentList:[Contact]!



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

    self.view.backgroundColor = utils.UIColorFromRGB(0x2B383E)

    topNav = TopNavigationView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1))
    self.view.addSubview(topNav)
    topNav.redrawCallback = handleTopBarChanged
    topNav.setup(self)

    currentList = dataMgr.contacts.contactList

    var nib = UINib(nibName: "PeopleCell", bundle: nil)
    peopleTable.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "peopleCell")

     var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 5 , target: self, selector: "resizeEverything", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    println("viewDidAppear")
}

override func updateViewConstraints()
{
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    println("updateViewConstraints")
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    println("viewWillLayoutSubviews")
 }

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    println("viewDidLayoutSubviews")

    handleTopBarChanged()
}

func handleTopBarChanged()
{
    mainView.frame.origin.y = topNav.getBottom() + 1
}


func resizeEverything()
{
    println("resizeEverything")

    mainView.frame.origin.y = 200

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, dataMgr.screenSize.width, dataMgr.screenSize.height)
    mainView.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.origin.x, mainView.frame.origin.y, dataMgr.screenSize.width, dataMgr.screenSize.height - mainView.frame.origin.y)

    peopleTable.frame = CGRectMake(peopleTable.frame.origin.x, peopleTable.frame.origin.y, dataMgr.screenSize.width, dataMgr.screenSize.height - mainView.frame.origin.y)

    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "setNeedsDisplay" is what's causing the subviews to layout again. Are you sure that line of code is necessary?

I think the easiest thing to do (if you only want to resize once) would be to move your resize code to viewWillAppear or simply set something like

```
private var didAlreadyResize = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    println("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
    if !didAlreadyResize {
        handleTopBarChanged()
        didAlreadyResize = true
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it happens without setNeedsDisplay, I put that in, in an attempt to force the screen to redraw. I was hoping for a less hacky way to do it than setting a flag.

Answer (score 0):

All my problems were happening because the nib file had the Use Auto Layout and Use Size Classes settings as true. This will cause the code to attempt to automatically reposition things on you and prevent you from resizing or moving any UI elements.

To fix, click on the view in the xib file. Click on the File Inspector tab in the Utilities view.
Uncheck Use Auto Layout and Use Size Classes.